# Flatlist breaks on loadmore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I seem to be having an issue with react native flat list that when I update the state on load more that the flat list just breaks. On initial load the flat list works as expected.

I have tried so many different ways to update the state but the result is always the same. I have run out of ideas of what could be causing this and I haven't been able to find anything on google that is the same issue I am having.

I haven't really built in react native before so my experience with some of its quirks are quite limited.

```
// React
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, FlatList} from "react-native";
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import {ray} from 'node-ray/web';

import AuthContext from "../../../auth/context";
import AppContainer from "../../../components/AppContainer";
import ChatContext from "../../../context/chats-context";
import ChatsApi from "../../../api/chats";
import Form from "../../../components/form/Form";
import FormInputDefault from "../../../components/form/FormInputDefault";
import FormIconButton from "../../../components/form/FormIconButton";
import RenderChatMessageItem from "../../../components/chat/RenderChatMessageBox";

import tw from "../../../lib/tailwind";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    message: Yup.string().required().label("Message"),
});

function SharedMessagesShow({ navigation, route }) {
    const chatContext = useContext(ChatContext);
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { data } = route.params;
    const [ chat, setChat ] =  useState(JSON.parse(data));
    const [ currentPage, setCurrentPage ] = useState(1);
    const [ maxListItems, setMaxListItems ] = useState(10);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

    const loadOlderMessages = async () => {

        if (loading) {
            return
        }

        setLoading(true);

        const response = await ChatsApi.getMoreMessages(chat.id, user.user.id, currentPage + 1);

        if (!response.ok) {
            return null;
        }

        if (maxListItems < response.data.total)
        {
            const newChat = {...chat};

            let newPage = currentPage + 1;
            let newMaxItems = maxListItems + response.data.messages.length;

            setCurrentPage(newPage);
            setMaxListItems(newMaxItems);

            newChat.messages = newChat.messages.concat(response.data.messages);

            ray(newChat);

            setChat(newChat);

            setLoading(false);
        }


    }

    const handleSendMessage = async ({message}, resetForm) => {
        const toUser = chat.users.find(chatUser => { return chatUser.user_id !== user.user.id })

        const response = await ChatsApi.sendMessage(chat.id, message, user.user.id, toUser.id);
        if (!response.ok) {
            return null;
        }

        const newChat = {...chat};

        newChat.messages.shift();
        newChat.messages.push(response.data);

        setChat(newChat);

        resetForm();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
    }, [chat, chat.messages, maxListItems]);


    return (
        <AppContainer bgColour={'gray-100'}>
            <View style={tw`justify-between flex flex-1`}>
                <View style={tw`bg-white p-3 flex flex-row justify-between items-center`}>
                    <View style={tw`flex`}>
                        <Text>{chat.to_user.first_name} {chat.to_user.last_name}</Text>
                        <Text>{chat.application.job_name}</Text>
                        <Text>{chat.application.status}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={tw`flex mr-3`}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat Calendar')}>
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name={'calendar-clock'} size={25} color={'#000000'}/>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={tw`flex flex-1 p-3`}>
                    <FlatList
                        inverted={true}
                        data={chat.messages}
                        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                        renderItem={ message => <RenderChatMessageItem message={message} fromUser={user.user}/> }
                        keyExtractor={ message => message.id.toString()}
                        onEndReached={loadOlderMessages}
                        extraData={maxListItems}
                        initialNumToRender={maxListItems}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={tw`flex w-full`}>
                    <Form
                        initialValues={{ message: "" }}
                        onSubmit={ (values, {resetForm}) => handleSendMessage(values, resetForm) }
                        validationSchema={validationSchema}
                    >
                        <View style={tw`flex flex-row w-full p-1`}>
                            <FormInputDefault
                                name="message"
                                placeholder="Message"
                                textContentType="none"
                                autoCapitalize="sentences"
                                autoCorrect={true}
                                multiline={true}
                                textAlignVertical={true}
                                scrollEnabled={true}
                                styles='w-5/6 bg-white flex px-8 pt-3 pb-1 rounded-3xl max-h-20'
                            />
                            <View style={tw`w-1/6 justify-center items-center`}>
                                <FormIconButton defaultText='+' />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Form>
                </View>
            </View>
        </AppContainer>
    );
}

export default SharedMessagesShow;
```

[image: load more breaks the list]
[image: initial load works]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this `loadMoreMessages` function:

```js
const [dataSlice, setDataSlice] = useState([]);
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

const loadOlderMessages = async () => {
  const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10; // what is the batch size you want to load.
  setPageNumber(prev => prev + 1);
  const start = pageNumber * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
  const end = (pageNumber + 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE - 1;

  const newData = maxListItems && maxListItems.slice(start, end); // here, we will receive next batch of the items
  setDataSlice([...dataSlice, ...newData]); // here we are appending new batch to existing batch
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I am using the loadMoreMessages method? Whats different really from your code to what I have? The only difference I can see really is spreading the messages which I have tried already and the same thing happens whats in the screenshot

Comment: Maybe it's because you  are fetching more items asynchronously in the `loadMoreMessages` . Try to first fetch all the items  in a `useEffect` and store them with a `useState` in an array. Then have them rendered per 10 in the `loadMoreMessages`.

Comment: Thank fotios. See thats what I think is the issue. Something to do with the InitalRenderItems on the flatlist however I have made sure that the number of items I am setting as the number is the amount of messages set e.g 13 messages and flatlist is set to 13. The api only returns 10 or less items at any time. SO I get a count of the items returned and then add them on top of the initial count e.g 10

Comment: so for example 13 3 10 - first is the count of message now set in the messages - second number is the length being returned by the server - third number is the amount already in the message length. I am using initialNumToRender as a useState which is updated when I call the loadMoreMessages which should work right?

Comment: Are you sure, it's ok to fetch data in a `loadMore` function for the `Flatlist`? Note, you have a `loadMore` which has an `async`! Have you tried to remove the fetching from the `loadMore` function?

Comment: I am using load more once the end has been reached which as far I am aware that would be how you load more data e.g like a chat and load older messages just liek whats app for example. How else would that be done?

Comment: Like I said before: Fetch all the items in the first render in a `useEffect` and store all of them with a `useState` in an array. Then have them rendered per 10 in the `loadMoreMessages`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Loading all data from the off will just cause performance issues.